# Windows 7 Action Center messages

Tags: powershell, windows-7, vbscript, wmi

I would like to know how to read, via vbscript, WMI, Powershell etc -the new Windows 7 Action center messages that the user normally gets informed of.

I want to read all those messages on each machine and store then in a central database, then disable the messages from displaying to the user on the local machines.

My questions are - 1. Where are these messages stored on the local Win7 systems and 2 -How do i programatically read those messages.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/perfmon/thread/97d01573-6f38-4203-8e58-f930dc891c7f) suggests that it may not be possible to hook into Action Center from a third-party application.

Comment: it would seem so, although i don't care to modify it in any way, i just want to get those messages in a database so my team can handle them from a central point