# How programmatically access to Action Center?

Tags: winapi

How to add message there? Where to start? Searching does not give results. Seems I cannot find right keywords..

Comment: Windows 7 SDK has no samples/ documentation?

Comment: Well, I made quick search and didn't found something useful. May be someone has link near. Of course, I continue to search.

Comment: check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661985/windows-7-action-center-messages). found on google via: 'windows 7 action center c#'

Answer (score 0):

The API is [confidential information](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/3e74dfe3-6f9b-4b0d-ada1-651536b669c6). You need to sign an Non-Disclosure Agreement to get the docs from Microsoft. Revealing those on a public web site is a breach of the agreement.